# The kth derivative of $f(x)=\log^2 x$ by induction, and the recurrence $a_k=(k-1) a_{k-1}+(k-2)!$

Tags: calculus, reference-request, proof-verification, induction, recurrence-relations

When I was working in my next post I've found the problem to compute the  kth derivative of $f(x)=\log^2 x$, for $x>0$,

> **Fact.** If $f(x)=\log^2 x$, for $x>0$, then the kth derivative, $k\geq 1$, is given by 
>   $$f^{k)}(x)=\frac{2(-1)^k}{x^k}(a_k-(k-1)!\cdot\log x)$$
>   where $a_1=0$ and $a_k=(k-1)a_{k-1}+(k-2)!$ when $k\geq 2$.

My question,

> **Question** a) I am looking for a proof verification of my proof of previous **Fact**. 
>   b) Suggestions to compute a closed solution for the cited sequence $a_k=(k-1)a_{k-1}+(k-2)!$ for $k>1$ and $a_1=0$. **c)(Optional and reissued)**  Can you provide us a proof or disproof that the sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is $A000254$, corresponding to unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind (see [1])?

My attempts were,

**Proof.** By mathematical induction.

*Step 1 (We prove that k=1 holds).* In a hand by the chain rule we obtain $f'(x)=(2\log x)\cdot 1/x$, and in the other hand $(2/x)\log x =(2(-1)^1/x^1)\cdot (0-0!\log x)$, we assume that $0!=1$.

*Step 2 (Induction statement).* We take as induction hypothesis that for every an integer $k>1$ the identity involving $f^{k)}(x)$ in **Fact** is true.

*Step 3 (We prove that $k\Rightarrow k+1$).* Deriving one more time using induction statement and the rule for the derivative of a product we obtain

$$f^{k+1)}=\frac{d}{dx} \left( f^{k}(x)\right)= 2(-1)^{k+1}x^{-k-1}k(a_k-(k-1)!\log x)+2(-1)^{k+1}x^{-k-1}(k-1)!$$
this is RHS is equal, when we use the recursion formula for $a_k$, to

$$\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}}{x^{k+1}}(ka_k+(k-1)!-k!\log x)=\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}}{x^{k+1}}(a_{k+1}-k!\log x),$$
and thus **we've finished the proof.**

For b) my attempt was work in substitutions of these kind:

$$a_{k+1}=k(k-1)a_{k-1}+(k-2)!\cdot k+(k-1)!$$

since $ka_k=k(k-1)a_{k-1}+(k-2)!\cdot k$, in the same way

$$a_{k+1}=k(k-1)(k-2)a_{k-2}+k(k-1)\cdot (k-3)!+(k-2)!\cdot k+(k-1)!.$$

I don't know if this is a good way to sum the general term. Neither if this sequence $a_k$ is known, see

For c) I search in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, the first six terms of the sequence $A000254$ match with us sequence since $(a_k)$ starts as

$$0, 1, 3, 11, 50, 274, 1764, 13068,\cdots$$

seems the same sequence. I don't know if this is obvious, today.

In my next post I want to essay a summation wth Euler Maclaurin formula, and I need know, previously derivatives of cited function $(\log (x))^2$ to try compute my error term. **Thanks in advance, I apprecite your help.**

References:

[1] https://oeis.org, The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, sequence $A000254$, Unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a)** It looks like your proof is appropriate.

**b)** It can be simply shown by induction that $a_{n}=(n-1)!\left(a_1+H_{n-1}\right)$ where $H_n$ is $n$th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$. Here $a_1=0$ so $a_n=(n-1)!H_{n-1}$.

Comment: Very thanks much @Constructor , in some hours I will study your answer and will accept if is the best.  Very thanks much for your statement.

Comment: I was wrong, in the fact that the terms 1694, 12132 are distinct from A000254, I will edit my post, because the correct terms are 1764 and 13068. Now, I have my head in other place, since it seems that my sequence and A000254 could be the same sequence, but seem have distinct recurrence formulas. In any case , I'll look your solution another day, but today I have to check it as good. Very thanks much for your proof. Now I will edit, and propose a new optional question. Thanks @Constructor